# Can I put the same Contact Form 7 shortcode on the top and bottom of a page in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have the same contact form 7 form on the top and bottom of a page.  Initially the top on is shown and then when the screen size shrinks the top one is hidden and the bottom one is shown.  Because it is the same shortcode/id, will I have problems getting this to work?

And if so, should I just duplicate the form, such that there will be different ids?

Comment: Duplicate the form with a different Id and name. Id's and names are always unique.

Comment: Great!  Thank you!